# changing the styling of one text element from inside another text element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

so basically, am trying to ***achieve*** something like so, such that when `+100` is pressed, the color of say, *Upload ID Card* changes to really show that that field is completed.

[image]

```
                      <View
                        style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", marginTop: 25 }}
                      >
                        <Text
                          style={ styles.scoreTitle }
                        >
                          {item.key}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.perScoreRightContentView}>
                        <Text
                          style={styles.scorePlus100}
                          onPress={() => // change style of the the text child above}
                        >
                          + 100
                        </Text>
                        <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-right" size={24} />
                      </View>
                    </View>
```

So, this is what I have tried out but with no success;

```
...
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = React.useState(false);
...          
                        <Text
                          style={[
                            isSelected
                              ? { ...styles.scoreTitle, color: "#C6C6C6" }
                              : styles.scoreTitle
                          ]}
                        >
                          {item.key}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.perScoreRightContentView}
                        onPress={() => setIsSelected(!isSelected)}
                      >
                        <Text style={styles.scorePlus100}>+ 100</Text>
                        <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-right" size={24} />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scoreTitle: {
    color: style.color.blackText,
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: style.fontFamily.medium
  }
});
```

Comment: still not clear, are trying to change the text style in that item ?

Comment: yes @AmirSaadallah, the one of ```{ item.key }```

Comment: Sorry but still not clear for me , if u want to change the style u already have style={styles.scoreTitle} !!

Comment: @AmirSaadallah, could you please checked out the image, update question

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand, you can put a ref on the text element and access to syle of that text element from the press function.
some thing like that :

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", marginTop: 25 }}>
  <Text style={ styles.scoreTitle } ref='colorText'>
    {item.key}
  </Text>
</View>
<View style={styles.perScoreRightContentView}>
  <Text style={styles.scorePlus100} onPress={() => changeStyle()}>
    + 100
  </Text>
  <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-right" size={24} />
</View>


const changeStyle = () => {
  const myReference = this.colorText.current // The DOM element
  myReference.style.color = "yellow";
}
```

don't forget to useRef to declar the ref.

Comment: actually @Amir Saadallah, it throws an error that the object ```myReference``` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution, thanks [rovas](https://github.com/rossenv)

So basically what had to be done was to split components such that they manage different state, that is to say,

```
const Score = ({ title }: { title: string }) => {
  const [scoreSelected, setScoreSelected] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.perSectionScore}>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", marginTop: 25 }}>
        <Text
          style={[
            scoreSelected
              ? { ...styles.scoreTitle, color: "#C6C6C6" }
              : styles.scoreTitle
          ]}
        >
          {title}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={styles.perScoreRightContentView}
      >
        <Text
          style={styles.scorePlus100}
          onPress={() => {
            setScoreSelected(!scoreSelected);
          }}
        >
          + 100
        </Text>
        <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-right" size={24} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

and then use in a to-be rendered component, i.e

```
            <View style={styles.scoresContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={scoreTitles}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            const index = scoreTitles.indexOf(item);

            return (
              <>
                {
                  <View
                    key={index}
                    style={{
                      padding: 10
                    }}
                  >
                    <Score title={item.key}/>
                    <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
                      <Input
                        disabled={true}
                        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: "#EAEAEA" }}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                }
              </>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

...
```